# How to read the … character and french accents from a text file

Tags: c++, filestream

I am given a text file that contains a couple character per line. I have to read it, line by line, and apply a lexical analyzer on each character. Then, I write my analysis in another file.

With the following code, I  have no problem reading french accents, but I realized that the character '**…**' *(this is one character not 3 dots)* is turned into a '**&**'.

Note: My lexical analyzer must use strings, that's why I converted back the wstring to a string.

```
wfstream SourceFile;
ofstream ResultFile (ResultFileName);

locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
SourceFile.imbue(utf8_locale);
SourceFile.open(SourceFileName);

while(getline(SourceFile, wLineBuffer)) 
{
    string LineBuffer( wLineBuffer.begin(), wLineBuffer.end() );

...
```

Edit: Raymond Chen figured that the character is lost because of my conversion from wstring to string.
So the new question is now : **How do I convert from a wstring to a string without transforming the characters ?**

Edit: file sample

```
"stringééé"
"ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
Identificateur1
Identificateur2
// Commentaire22
/**/
/*
Autre commentaire
…
*/
```

Comment: Are you sure that the text file you are given is UTF-8?

Comment: Is the ellipsis lost at the `getline` or at the conversion from `wstring` to `string`?

Comment: @DidierTrosset Yes, when I open it with notepad2, I go to encoding, and it says utf-8.

Comment: @RaymondChen holy crap you found it, the ... is fine when I debug and watch wLineBuffer, but gets transformed into & when I convert to string ! How do I fix this ?

Comment: `string` cannot represent all the characters that `wstring` can. (Otherwise, what would be the point of having `wstring` if it is the same as `string`?) It appears that whatever encoding you're using cannot represent `…` in a `string`.

Comment: Yeah it totally makes sense. Well I guess I have to change the whole code to use wstring ?

Comment: It is up to you how to decide to deal with it. One is to ignore the `…`. Another is to convert it to three characters `...`. Another is to encode the `…` into one or more `char`s somehow (e.g. re-encode in utf-8), and teach your lexical analyzer to recognize the special encoding. Another is to work with `wstring` throughout.

Comment: Using `std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>` is somewhat of a red flag. What is it you’re reading (what encoding), and what is it you’re using that reports an ‘&’?

Comment: `std::string` is a sequence of bytes and as such it can represent whatever you choose to interpret it as.

Answer (score 4):

You need a proper Unicode support library. Forget using the broken Standard functions. They were not designed to support Unicode, don't support Unicode, and cannot be extended to support it properly. Look into using ICU or Boost.Locale or something like that.